# PostgesSQL - SELECT rows only for the latest range found

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-design, relational-database

I have this select statement

> SELECT  id, liked, markers, search_body, remote_bare_jid, direction 
>   FROM mam_message where   user_id='20' AND remote_bare_jid =
>   '5a95c47078f92c6337019521' ORDER BY id DESC;

that returns the following

[image]
 I want to retrieve rows of the latest range direction 'I' -> 'I'

THIS:

```
SELECT id, liked, markers, search_body, remote_bare_jid, direction
 FROM mam_message 
 where user_id ='20' 
 AND remote_bare_jid = '5a95c47078f92c6337019521' 
 ORDER BY id DESC 
 limit 4;
```

[image]

Even when the range is not on top

[image]

I am still able to get only the latest range of direction 'I'

THIS (the highligted):
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by 'count of the latest range?' Please repost your question in text form not as a pic and show your expected results as well

Comment: look for `CONTIGUOUS` OPs... I got a similar solution to this OP.

Comment: @DanielMarcus, I think the pics help to illustrate what I want to achieve, I did some editing...

Comment: @user1000622 : [Question: WHAT IS YOUR QUERY TO GET the top??] look at my question in your post

Comment: @âńōŋŷXmoůŜ I used `SELECT id, liked, markers, search_body, remote_bare_jid, direction FROM mam_message where user_id='20' AND remote_bare_jid = '5a95c47078f92c6337019521' ORDER BY id DESC limit 4;` ONLY to display what I wanted to achieve

Comment: @user1000622 why did you use limit 4? you want to get the top 4 records with consecutive DIRECTION = I order by Id desc?

Comment: @âńōŋŷXmoůŜ . Like I said, I only used limit to show the result that I want to achieve, I know the query would not need any limit... and yes I want the last rows consecutive DIRECTION = I

Comment: so even if only two consecutive direction=I on top, you will display this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169200/discussion-between-anxmous-and-user1000622).

Comment: @âńōŋŷXmoůŜ correcting myself, it should be either the last consecutive rows  DIRECTION = I OR the last alone row DIRECTION = I

Answer (score 1):

You can find *transition rows* (where `direction` changes from O to I) using the window function `lag().` Mark these rows as 1 (0 the others). Next, calculate cumulative sum of these marks. The group sought will have the sum = 1. Example:

```
with example(id, direction) as (
values
    (1, 'O'),
    (2, 'I'),
    (3, 'I'),
    (4, 'I'),
    (5, 'O'),
    (6, 'I')
)

select id, direction
from (
    select id, direction, sum(mark) over w
    from (
        select 
            id, direction, 
            (lag(direction, 1, 'O') over w = 'O' and direction = 'I')::int mark
        from example
        window w as (order by id)
        ) s
    window w as (order by id)
    ) s
where direction = 'I' and sum = 1
order by id

 id | direction 
----+-----------
  2 | I
  3 | I
  4 | I
(3 rows)
```

Comment: can you explain why direction is 1 or 0

Comment: This is an example data to illustrate the algorithm. I have no idea why direction is 1 or 0 in your data, you should know this.

Comment: direction is not one or zero in the table, it's `I`  for Incoming or `O` outgoing

Comment: Ops, my weak eyes, sorry. I've changed this, however this doesn't matter for the algorithm.

Comment: thank you, I tried your solution with variations of example you provided above. Works almost as expected, for example when using example `with example(id, direction) as (
values
    (323, 'I'),
    (31, 'I'),
    (43, 'I'),
    (22, 'I'),
    (123, 'I'),
    (09, 'I'),
    (88, 'I'),
    (912839418234, 'O'),
    (81283, 'I'),
    (4193, 'O'),
    (3538382, 'O'),
    (655, 'I'),
    (622, 'I'),
    (6332, 'I'),
    (6524, 'I')
)` I would expect result 7 rows `I` however it results with 9 rows

Comment: You've forgotten that your results are ordered by id. You should expect 9 rows, see [DbFiddle.](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=6997e773a1d956ff5d71385ee8fd142f) (Actually this should be the descending order, but this also doesn't matter)

Comment: Change: both `window w as (order by id desc)` in the query to get it working in desc order.